# 1 1 1 [ 0.] 84.714 : Why are the brackets getting printed?

Tags: python, brackets

I have written a python code as follows:

```
Output= str(i) + ' ' + str(j) + ' ' + str(k) + ' ' + str(data[i,j,k]) + ' ' + str(mep_value)
```

I dont understand why the output of str(data[i,j,k]) has brackets:[ 0.]

Here, data[i,j,k] is the value at the coordinates (i,j,k). How could I just print the value (without brackets)?

Comment: What is `data`? What is `data[i,j,k]`?

Comment: This could probably look much better with `.format()` approach.

Comment: data[i,j,k] is the value at the coordinates (i,j,k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are casting a list or a list like object to string .

```
In [1]: str([1])
Out[1]: '[1]'
```

You can use type(data[i,j,k]) to see what kind of object you are casting .

Comment: There's no guessing - this is what OP is doing: `str(data[i,j,k])`

Comment: What i am guessing is what type OP is casting . Not whether OP is casting .

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen Your array must look like that `a = np.array([[[1],[2]] ,  [[2],[3]]])` ,  the element a[i,j,k] is a list not a number , casting a list to string will keep brackets in result .

Comment: I am looking to print the value at coordinates (i,j,k). So say in coordinates data(1,1,1) the value  is 0.0 and I would want to print out this value. How could I do that? Instead of printing [0.0]

Comment: The value can't be `0.0` according to your question. The value must be `[0.0]`. Use `print(type(data[i,j,k]))` to see the type of this value.

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen According to your question , the value can't be `0.0` . Use `type()` to check your element .

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it!

```
It is str(float(data[i,j,k]))
```